# Adobe Flash cs6 actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to ask about my project, here is my problem, I want to make kind of quiz that if I fill it with right answer the pop up question is dissapear, then if I fill it with wrong answer it will go to game over scene,,

What kind of actionscript that I have to use for my problem above?

Big thanks to anyone who help,,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. From the above post, What is your actual **question**? Nobody knows which part of your project is the difficult part for you. Use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57274144/edit) to add more details that we can read and say _"Ok, this is the answer for that"_...

Comment: Since you asked me... I'm wondering if there's a specific reason to use Flash for this? This would be more convenient in in simple HTML/Javascript. Try googling "build javscript quizz" and there are already a few example tutorials.

Comment: Is it?  Well I'd better try that way,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality your trying to achieve Like the above post you can use javascript for a simple quiz if your looking for something more visually appealing i.e. (animations) it would probably be easier in as3 using animate.